# Integrate Doctrine Extensions into my ZF / Doctrine 2 project

Tags: zend-framework, doctrine-orm

I want to do this to be able to take advantage of Gedmo translatable to translate values in my tables. I already  have Doctrine working in my project, but I don't know how to add these extensions : [doctrine extensions](https://github.com/l3pp4rd/DoctrineExtensions)

I am using [ZF Boilerplate](http://zf-boilerplate.com/) and apparently it should be fairly simple, but I am lost. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add namespace:

```
autoloaderNamespaces.app[] = "Gedmo"
```

Add event subscriber:

```
resources.doctrine.dbal.connections.default.eventSubscribers[] = "Gedmo\Translatable\TranslatableListener"
```

Add annotation driver:

```
resources.doctrine.orm.entityManagers.default.metadataDrivers.annotationRegistry.annotationNamespaces.0.namespace   = "Gedmo"
resources.doctrine.orm.entityManagers.default.metadataDrivers.annotationRegistry.annotationNamespaces.0.includePath = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library"
```

Answer (score 1):

I realize this was posted some time ago, and this might be a shot in the dark, but adding these two lines to my application.ini config did the trick for me:

```
resources.doctrine.orm.entityManagers.default.metadataDrivers.annotationRegistry.annotationNamespaces.0.namespace   = "Gedmo"
resources.doctrine.orm.entityManagers.default.metadataDrivers.annotationRegistry.annotationNamespaces.0.includePath = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library/vendors"
```

Hope this helps someone!